# How to find the frame id of a bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, bag-to-pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I recorded a bag file to fetch the /camera/rgb/points topic published by a kinect with

```
rosbag record /camera/rgb/points
```

I am able to play the file back and see the pointclouds in rviz
When i try to convert this bag to pcd using

```
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd source.bag /camera/rgb/points .
```

I get the following error

```
Saving recorded sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 messages on topic /camera/rgb/points to .
[ERROR] [1321569889.237783893]: Frame id /base_link does not exist! Frames (1): 
Segmentation fault
```

I tried changing the /base_link in the bag_to_pcd.cpp to /openni_camera but its not working even then.
I guess the frame id has to appropriate and I am missing something here. So help me figure out the frame id of the recorded pointcloud in my bag file.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

After recording the bag file with /tf included and then doing the bag_to_pcd gives me the following error

```
[ERROR] [1321638863.658386805]: Frame id /base_link does not exist! Frames (6): Frame /openni_depth_frame exists with parent /openni_camera.
Frame /openni_camera exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /openni_depth_optical_frame exists with parent /openni_depth_frame.
Frame /openni_rgb_optical_frame exists with parent /openni_rgb_frame.
Frame /openni_rgb_frame exists with parent /openni_camera.

Segmentation fault
```

So the Frame id is still a problem here?.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

After running the static transform publisher while recording i get the following error while converting

```
[ERROR] [1321643793.300622410]: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/openni_rgb_optical_frame] to frame [/base_link]
Segmentation fault
```

I am not sure what we are doing here. Can you give me the links where significance of this can be learnt?

Thanks
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11978/how-to-find-the-frame-id-of-a-bag-file/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quick look at the source code for bag_to_pcd shows that it wants to use TF. The quick solution is to record tf in addition to the point cloud with:

```
rosbag record /camera/rgb/points /tf
```

It looks like the tf frame is hard coded to "base_link", however there should probably be an option to set the frame. You might consider ticketing this as a future improvement.

Update:
Ok, so then you are lacking a base_link. You can create a base_link to openni transform by running the following (when you are collecting the bag file!):

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link openni_camera 100
```

Alternatively, you could edit the source to bag_to_pcd.cpp to use one of your existing links.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-18**:
Thanks Fregs. I updated my question again.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-11-18**:
There should be an issue tracker on the pointclouds.org site (I would recommend using that one since pcl_ros appears to be in their SVN repo). You might send an email to pcl-users mailing list to get more help.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-18**:
Fergs,I have updated my question with the latest error. Pls let me know the mistake

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-18**:
How do i ticket this as a future improvement

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-17**:
As a general rule, you should just always record /tf. Just about everything uses it in some way.